# XTerm is killing last line's characters

Tags: linux, ssh, xterm

I'm using cssh (aka clusterssh) to manage an experimental, peer-to-peer system, and I've observed a curious behaviour: the terminals seem to kill the last character that should appear on each line, i.e. I get

```
Iproto)=7d59d8fa (Isrc)=00001011 (Idst)=0bcf (Tsrc)@>> in <RouterVisitor:['b
cpe+f', "scanning rings @0.442442758736: [(True, -0.641888605544--0.55755724
264, 'L')]", '<Node--102--0.624, <NameID::4xjg2> :: EQ:-& (Idst > 00001388 (
dst)) & (Isrc < 558b5f84 (Isrc)) & (Idst > 0000196f (Idst)) & (Idst < 00001c
```

while I should instead have

```
Iproto)=7d59d8fa (Isrc)=00001011 (Idst)=0bcf (Tsrc)@>> in <RouterVisitor:['by
cpe+f', "scanning rings @0.442442758736: [(True, -0.641888605544--0.55755724?
264, 'L')]", '<Node--102--0.624, <NameID::4xjg2> :: EQ:-& (Idst > 00001388 (I
dst)) & (Isrc < 558b5f84 (Isrc)) & (Idst > 0000196f (Idst)) & (Idst < 00001c?
```

(? are for characters which I know should be there to match e.g. float precision, but which I don't precisely know)

Is that something that is known from XTerm (I usually use other terminals)?  Is there any configuration file I should check?

---

I note, by the way, that windows created by clusterssh for the terminals can be resized at pixel-level precision, rather than at character-level precision as a regular xterm window would on this system (Ubuntu+e16 window manager).

Comment: I would guess that $COLUMNS is 76 but the window width is at least one pixel too narrow for the 76th character. Perhaps cssh has an out-by-one bug that prevents it from reporting a reduced width correctly whilst preventing it from rendering the last column which is one-pixel too narrow.

Comment: as far as tests go, it looks like I'm actually killing that last column myself, when stretching the window vertically for better readability. The fact that it's resizing pixel-per-pixel implies that there's less resistance towards the deletion of a column...

Comment: Off toppic here but it may interest other visitors: I've got troubles with keyboard configurations. If I reprogram the keyboard, certain keys are ignored by cssh, certain keys start to play some other roles, etc. If I reconfigure my keyboard to the "default", cssh returns to "normal". So, cssh does not play well in some modern window managers.